# Postgres, order by SUM of column in child table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following (simplified) tables

products - `id` `name`

order_products - `quantity`, `product_id`

I would like to order the rows from `products` table based on the sum of `quantity` column in `order_products` for every product

If `order_products` has these rows

```
quantity - product_id
2        - 555
2        - 555
6        - 666
3        - 777
```

I want the results to be ordered like that: `666, 555, 777`

666 has 6 quantity, 555 has 4 and 777 has 3

I ended up using slightly modified version of the answer, as my requirement was to include `products` even if they don't have any relations in `order_products` table.

```
select p.*, coalesce(sum(op.quantity), 0) quantity_sold
from products p
left outer join order_products as op on op.product_id = p.id
group by p.id
order by quantity_sold desc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `ORDER BY` and aggregate function

```
select p.product_id, p.name, sum(quantity) quantity_sold
from order_products op
join products p on op.product_id = p.product_id
group by p.product_id, p.name
order by sum(quantity) desc
```

Comment: I want to select the rows from the `products` table, not `order_products` and its not clear to me how I should write it so that each product then has a `quantity_sold` column, which is the sum of `quantity` for every row for that product

Comment: Okay, I spotted what was wrong with my initial query. My requirement is that `products` must be included even if there are no relations in `order_products`, so `LEFT OUTER` join must be used. This, however, causes NULL to appear in the `quantity_sold` column, so it must be combined with COALESCE and it ended up working as I wanted it to